# MockK test member function getting NullPointerException

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

The class under test looks like:

```
class State(pivate val repo){
    val values = listOf<Int>()
    fun update() {
        values = repo.generateValues() // <-line 375
    }
}
```

The unit test looks like:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
private class StateTest {
    @MockK(relaxed = true) private lateinit var mockedRepo: Repo
    @BeforeAll
    fun config() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        clearAllMocks()
        unmockkAll()
    }

    @Test
    fun `invoke update`() {
        val state = mockk<State>(relaxed = true)

        every { state.repo } answers { mockedRepo }
        every { mockedRepo.generateValues() } returns listOf(1,2,3)
        every { state.update() } answers { callOriginal() }

        state.update()
        Assertions.assertTrue(state.values.size > 0)
    }
}
```

Runnig the test, a NullPointerException is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.name.someapp.someservice.State.update(State.kt:375)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.MethodCall.call(MethodCall.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.SelfCallEliminatorCallable.call(SelfCallEliminatorCallable.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper.handleOriginalCall(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:95)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper.access$handleOriginalCall(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:18)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1$invocation$$inlined$stdFunctions$lambda$1.invoke(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:27)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub$handleInvocation$originalPlusToString$1.invoke(MockKStub.kt:230)
    at io.mockk.MockKAnswerScope.callOriginal(API.kt:2205)
```

Comment: if `State` class is under test, why are you instantiating it with mock? why not `State(mockRepo)` ?

Comment: The reason I mock the `State` is: that class is not really the thing I am working on. The real class has a long list of arguments in the primary constructor plus dozen of private fields in the initializer block. I do not know how to mock private fields in the initializer block (the mockk doc does not mention and there is a stackover not answered question about that). And there are no existing unit test. I only need to add a new function `update` which changes one private field. So I am trying to avoid to mock other things. Yeah, basically, I am saying I am lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting the NullPointerException is that `fun update()` does not call `getRepo()` (which you've mocked) but instead it uses the backing field `repo` directly. (You can see this by compiling the Kotlin source to bytecode and decompiling to Java in IntelliJ IDEA.) This is also documented at [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties):

> ⓘ On the JVM: Access to private properties with default getters and setters is optimized to avoid function call overhead.

The answer is, as `sidgate` said in the comment, to create a real (not mock) instance of `State` and pass the mock repo to it constructor:

```
val state = State(mockRepo)
```

It is a code smell to mock the "system under test".